# ArrayList - Count if the same Object i listed exact 2 times and if: append to "tempFinalFilterSearchList"

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Basicly im trying to look through an Arraylist to check if the same object is listed 2 times - and if: append to "tempFinalFilterSearchList"

Im not allowed to use Hashmap (School assignment).

**UPDATE - This code actual works now... Now I just need to remove dublicates from "tempFinalFilterSearchList"**

```
public List<Venue> filterToFinalSearchList()
        {

            for (int i=0; i < tempFilterSearchList.size(); i++)
            {

                int occurences=0;

                for (int j = 0; j < tempFilterSearchList.size(); j++)
                {

                    if (tempFilterSearchList.get(i).getVenueId() == tempFilterSearchList.get(j).getVenueId())
                    {
                        occurences++;
                    }

                }

                if (occurences == 2)
                {
                    tempFinalFilterSearchList.add(tempFilterSearchList.get(i));
                }
            }
            return tempFinalFilterSearchList;
        }
```

- if the same venueId is listed exact 2 times in "tempfilterSearchList", then the Object have to be added to "tempFinalFilterSearchList"...
- have tried several different things now, without luck - And also search here / google - there alot of solutions, but all with Hashmap which im not allowed to use.

Thank you in advance for any advise.

Comment: Let me give you a hint...you need to "count" somewhere the object within the arraylist that has those venueId equals to 3. If that count is actually >=3 then you proceed to erase the ojbects in the arraylist with that venueId. I mean, you could strive the problem using two loops. One for counting, and one for deleting (if is that the case)

Comment: You're testing if the VenueId of an element is different than 3. That doesn't test if the same object is present 3 times in the list. Start by doing that: write a method that takes a list and an object as argument, and which returns the number of times the object is in the list. Then write another method which calls the first one for every element of the list. If the first method returns 3, remove the object from the list. And of course to do that, you'll need to write a third method which takes a list and an object as argument, and removes every occurrence of the object from the list.

Comment: What range your ids go?

Comment: @VidorVistrom Im not sure i understand your question ?.

Comment: Integer values that your id can hold... Like 1,2,...100

Comment: there is a max of 50 ids

Comment: @LiamBlake 0 to 50?

Comment: @VidorVistrom the Id's is retrieved from SQL DB - but the DB can max hold 50 id's.

Comment: UPDATE - Above code actual works perfect now - Now I just have an issue with Dubplicates in "tempFinalFilterSearchList".

Answer (score 3):

First of all keep in mind that using the remove function inside a loop for the same list is not safe(Unless using an iterator).
I assume you have a class let's call it **A** that has the attribute **venueId**.
It looks something like this + other attributes that you want:

```
public class A {
    private int venueId;

    public A(int venueId) {
        this.venueId = venueId;
    }

    public int getVenueId() {
        return venueId;
    }

    public void setVenueId(int venueId) {
        this.venueId = venueId;
    }
}
```

1.Create a function that parses the list and counts the number of times an object with the same **venueId** repeats itself

```
public boolean doesVenueIdRepeatInList(int venueId, List<A> list) {
    int timesRepeated = 0;

    //Parse the list and count the number of items that have the same venueId
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getVenueId() == venueId) {
            timesRepeated++;
        }
    }

    //If the venueId repeats more than 3 times
    if (timesRepeated >= 3) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

3.Now to the code that actually does what you asked.
We will parse the list and identify the the objects that repeat more than 3 times.
If they repeat more than 3 times we won't add them to the new list

```
List<A> tempFilterSearchList = Arrays.asList(
        new A(1),
        new A(2),
        new A(1),
        new A(2),
        new A(3),
        new A(1),
        new A(2)
);

//We will be using a new list to put the result in
//It's not safe to use the delete function inside a loop
List<A> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

//Count the number an object repeats and if it repeats more than 3 times store it inside repeatedVenueIds
for (int i=0; i < tempFilterSearchList.size(); i++)
{
    int venueId = tempFilterSearchList.get(i).getVenueId();
    boolean itRepeat3Times = doesVenueIdRepeatInList(venueId, tempFilterSearchList);

    //If it doesn't repeat more than 3 times add it to the new list
    if(!itRepeat3Times) {
        filteredList.add(tempFilterSearchList.get(i));
    }
}
```

You have your result inside **filteredList**

Comment: This way - the method needs "venueId" - the "venueId" is in the list... 
( tempFilterSearchList )

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that and why is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is a better advanced option to use 'iterator' since it allows you to remove elements while iterating an arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer> tempFilterSearchList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,5,3,7,3,7,3) );
    Iterator itr = tempFilterSearchList.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        int count = 0;
        int number = (Integer)itr.next();
        for (int i=0; i < tempFilterSearchList.size(); i++)
        {
            int x = tempFilterSearchList.get(i);
            if (x == number)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if( count != 3 )
        {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
```

"using the remove function inside a loop for the same list is not safe. " this will not be an issue if you use iterator in java which is a advance option in java language

Comment: "using the remove function inside a loop for the same list is not safe. " this will not be an issue if you use iterator in java which is a advance option in java language

Answer (score 0):

Your code must look like the folowing. First of all you should loop over all the elements in tempFilterSearchList. Then for each element, you should count the number of times it appears in the list. I choosed rather to place all the positions where the current elements' venueId occures in separate List to further delete them easly.

```
ArrayList<Integer> occurrences = new ArrayList<Integer>()
for (int i=0; i < tempFilterSearchList.size(); i++)
    for (int j=0; j < tempFilterSearchList.size(); j++){
        if(tempFilterSearchList.get(i).getVenueId() ==tempFilterSearchList.get(j).getVenueId()){
            occurrences.add(j)
        }
    }

    if(occurrences.size() != 3){
        for(int j:occurrences){
            tempFilterSearchList.remove(occurrences[j])
        }     
    }
}
```